# Proof that if $A\in \mathcal{O}$, then $A^b \in \mathcal{O}\,\forall b\ge 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, contest-math, permutation-matrices

> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the set of $n\times n$ matrices with integer entries so that for every nonempty subset $S$ of $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$, the $|S|$ by $|S|$ submatrix $(a_{ij})_{i,j \in S}$ has odd determinant. Prove that if $A\in\mathcal{O}$, then for every $b\ge 1, A^b \in \mathcal{O}$.

I know it suffices to work with matrices over the field of two elements since only parity matters for the determinant.

> Why is it true that if there exists a permutation matrix $P$ so that $P^{-1} AP$ is unipotent (i.e. has 1s on the main diagonal and 0s below it), then $A\in\mathcal{O}$?

> Is it true that any principal submatrix of $A$ is conjugate to a principal submatrix of $P^{-1} AP$ and if so, why?

Since $P^{-1} AP$ is unipotent implies that $(P^{-1} AP)^k$ is unipotent, it suffices to show that for any element $A$ of $\mathcal{O}$, there exists a permutation matrix $P$ so that $P^{-1} AP$ is unipotent.

Let the $(i,j)$th element of $A$ be $a_{ij}$.
To show that such a permutation matrix exists, let $S = \{i\}$ to see that $a_{ii}=1$. Form a directed graph on the vertex set $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ with an edge from $i$ to $j$ whenever $a_{ij} = 1$ and claim the graph has no cycles. This can be seen because if there was a cycle $i_1, i_2,\cdots, i_c$ of minimal length, then $a_{i_j i_k} = \begin{cases}1,&\text{ if $k-j\equiv 0,1 \mod c$ }\\
0,&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$ (if $a_{i_j i_k} = 1$ and $k-j\not\equiv 0, 1\mod m$, then we can assume WLOG that $j < k$ and delete the edges in between $i_j$ and $i_k$, which yields a contradiction as there must be at least one edge between $i_j$ and $i_k$). But then note that the row sum of the submatrix corresponding to $S=\{i_1,\cdots, i_m\}$ is $0$ (in the field of 2 elements, $0$ and $1$), which contradicts the fact that $S$ must be nonzero by hypothesis.

We proceed by induction on $n$ where the base case $n=1$ follows from above. Since the directed graph has no cycles, there must be some vertex $i$ that is not the starting point of any edge (i.e. has outdegree zero), and this can be proven using the Pigeonhole principle and the finiteness of the directed graph.

> By the inductive hypothesis, there exists a permutation matrix $P$ so that the submatrix $A'$  corresponding to $S=\{1,\cdots, n\}\backslash \{i\}$ satisfies that $P^{-1}A'P$ is unipotent. But how can I obtain a permutation matrix $P_2$ from this one that makes $P_2^{-1} AP_2$ unipotent? I know that by the definition of the directed graph, since vertex $i$ has outdegree zero, there is no entry $a_{ji}$ equal to $1$.

Comment: If you add  (subtract) a row to row(s) determinant does not change. The same with columns. Note the matrix at the question should have $1$ entry at $a_{11}$. Then you use it to zero all other entries in the first row and column. Plus induction.

Comment: This is Problem B5 on the 2021 Putnam competition

Comment: See the discussions on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2731222p23794726).